# Google Results as NSArray or something similar

Tags: objective-c, web-services, cocoa-touch

My boss has asked me to do something with Google results.

Basically, I have a table view with a search bar set up.

My goal is to have the search bar push the request to Google, and Google returns it's results in a form I can use to populate the table view, and a cell can be tapped to go to that webpage.

The part I am stuck on is the pushing the request/returning the request as an "array"?

Now, this is all meant to be used in the long run as a web service application.

Comment: The closest thing Google offers to an API for its search results is the Custom Search API, which searches over a subset of domains.

Comment: This may seem really vague, but can you clarify to what a web service is? Or any easier method to get the ropes on it? Or will a simple tutorial search help?

Comment: The ones I have found have all the links to external resources dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done very easily. Just make RESTful API requests for JSON-encoded search results from Google (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview), and then parse the results into Objective-C data structures that can easily be bound to UI elements using a library such as SBJSON (http://stig.github.com/json-framework/).